# Get Red, Blue or Green channel from Android Color object

Tags: java, android, colors

I feel this is a pretty stupid question, but the Android Color class doesn't seem to have a method to get an int from the R, G, B channels from a Color object individually. Can I get the channels somehow like java.awt's Color can?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.someColor);
        int red = Color.red(color);
        int blue = Color.blue(color);
        int green = Color.green(color);
        int alpha = Color.alpha(color);
```

Comment: I don't want the color from a resource file or anything, I just want to get it from a Color object I made programatically. Am I going to have to get the hex somehow and parse it to get the channels? If that's even possible cause from what I can see this class has very little knowledge.

Comment: how you made the color object then?

Comment: I just realized I never tried initializing an android.graphics.Color object, I only had a Color object in a parameter. Is there no equivalent to java's java.awt.Color on android to work with colors programatically?

Comment: In Android color values is hold as integer. And if you want to do some operation using that Color value then you have a Color class but it is helper class not actual color value container like AWT.

Answer (score 2):

> Did you mean

```
int colorValue=Color.parseColor(#121212);
int red=Color.red(colorValue);
int green=Color.green(colorValue);
int blue=Color.blue(colorValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
String myPassedColor = "#ffffff";
int color = Color.parseColor(myPassedColor)
int r = Color.red(color);
int g = Color.green(color);
int b = Color.blue(color);
int a = Color.alpha(color);
```